# Restoring correct file permissions for /var/

Tags: files, chmod

Whilst running some chmod commands for Oxid 6, I made the rookie mistake of not double checking what was written fully and managed to `chmod 777 /var -R` as part of my command

How can I restore the default file permissions on `/var/*` for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Comment: That will very much depend on what backup strategy you have implemented?  How are we to know?   As for manually correcting the file permissions, it'll depend on what package(s) & changes you have made post-install; you can always create a VM of the same system & then get what needs to be corrected from that; otherwise just grab them from your backups.

Comment: I was hoping someone would be able to provide a chmod that would set the default file permissions on the standard /var/* folders or packages

Comment: That will only exist if you've created such a backup strategy...  Most of use don't use default systems (*and even a default system has no specific single value*) as permissions vary across packages etc... We keep backups so we can undo mistakes (*we all make mistakes!*)  and what you did is something a lot of us did...  Backups are your answer; restore those backups; or create a script (*what I've done*) copying the permissions from your backups; OR a new system installed to replicate what you had & thus can get the details from...  Restoring data is by far fastest...  My 2c.